# ASP.NET MVC 2 Display Name DataAnnotaion from Resource not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, .net-4.0, data-annotations

I'm trying to use a resource file to hold label text for the Model in an MVC 2 project.

I've got the following class...

```
public class Person
{
    [Display(ResourceType = typeof(Resources.Labels),Name="First")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

...and have tried using...

```
    <%: Html.EditorForModel() %>
    <%: Html.EditorFor(m => m) %>
    <%: Html.LabelFor(m => m.FirstName) %>
```

...but I'm getting "FirstName" for the label in all instances.  Resource file is called Labels.resx, has an entry for "First" and is in Properties folder.

Having read a few posts, I believe this should work in .NET 4 (I'm using VS2010 RTM and have targetted .NET 4).

Should this work?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6):

http://weblogs.asp.net/rajbk/archive/2010/04/27/localization-in-asp-net-mvc-2-using-modelmetadata.aspx

Comment: This did it for me even though I am using MVC 3! I doubt I'd ever try changing the build action of the resx to "Embedded Resource". Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

must be like below ;

```
[Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources), ErrorMessageResourceName = "Required")]
```